# Laravel validation error not showing in view, only showing in 422 post error

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I am have trouble figuring out why laravel validation error message are not showing in my current blade view file when I try to send a post request without an title input.

I would get a 422 post error. 
**[image]**

**upload.blade.php**

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
     <div class = "alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
           @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
              <li>{{ $error }}</li>
           @endforeach
        </ul>
     </div>
@endif

<input type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="enter post title" />
```

**uploadcontroller.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $photos = $request->file('file');
   $title = $request->input('title');

   $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required|max:120',
   ]);
}
```

When I inspect the 422 POST error, only then it shows the error message

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a standard form, you need to **return** back to the view in order to see the error.  Something like:

```
return \Redirect::back() // can send errors, or with() or whatever
```

If you are using ajax to send your info, you'll need to handle the response via the `success` or `error` method, depending on how you wish to handle the error.  Your `store()` method would then send some kind of text back to ajax in this case.

Bottom line, you need to return something from your `store()` method to get back to the view you were on, else you won't see anything unless you inspect it.

Comment: I thought using laravel validation method in the controller automatically redirect back on failure with errors.